# C string length - is this valid code?

Tags: c, string, char, expression

Is this type of expression in C valid (on all compilers)?
If it is, is this good C?

```
char cloneString (char clone[], char string[], int Length)
{

    if(!Length)
        Length=64
    ;

    int i = 0
    ;

    while((clone[i++] = string[i]) != '\0', --Length)
    ;

    clone[i] = '\0';

    printf("cloneString = %s\n", clone);

};
```

Would this be better, worse, indifferent?

```
char *cloneString (char clone[], char string[], int Length)
{

    if(!Length)
        Length=STRING_LENGTH
    ;

    char *r = clone
    ;

    while
    (   //(clone[i++] = string[i]) != '\0'
        *clone++ = *string++
    ,   --Length
    );

    *clone = '\0';

    return clone = r
    ;

    printf("cloneString = %s\n", clone);

};
```

Stackoverflow wants me to add more text to this question!

Okay! I'm concerned about

a.) expressions such as c==(a=b)
b.) performance between indexing vs pointer

Any comments?

Thanks so much.

Comment: First of all, syntax: put semicolons on the same line as their statement. You don't need to close the function body with a semicolon after the closing curly bracket. Use lowercase names for variables having primitive type. Then semantics: don't do four operations in one line - do them in four. It's easier to understand. Additionally, your `while` loop contains undefined behaviour.

Comment: It will compile, but it won't do what you want.  The comparison with `'\0'` is completely ignored.

Comment: if(!Length)
        Length=64 ?

Comment: focus on readability. Performance is misleading for someone who doesn’t grasp some concepts very well. Compiler are smart enough to generate optimal code regardless if you access an array indexed or via pointers (with appropriate flags). Just focus on READABILITY.

Comment: bolov, how about you tell me what your philosophy on readability is. I don't know what your opinion of readability is, so how would I know what to modify this to look like?

Comment: What I meant was to write code that come naturally, instead of resorting to gimmicks that you think might improve speed. For instance, instead of `for(int *p = v; p != v + size; ++p) {*p =...}` you should write `for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) {v[i] = ...}` even though the first variant will be in theory faster. The compiler will take care of the second one and generate most probably the same code. Write what feels natural in the sense of understanding the code. That’s what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's syntactically valid on all compilers (though semantically valid on none), and no, it isn't considered good C. Most developers will agree that the comma operator is a bad thing, and most developers will generally agree that a single line of code should do only one specific thing. The `while` loop does a whole *four* and has undefined behavior:

- it increments `i`;
- it assigns `string[i]` to `clone[i++]`; (**undefined behavior**: you should use `i` only once in a statement that increments/decrements it)
- it checks that `string[i]` isn't 0 (**but discards the result of the comparison**);
- it decrements `Length`, and terminates the loop if `Length == 0` after being decremented.

Not to mention that assuming that `Length` is 64 if it wasn't provided is a terrible idea and leaves plenty of room for more undefined behavior that can easily be exploited to crash or hack the program.

I see that you wrote it yourself and that you're concerned about performance, and this is apparently the reason you're sticking everything together. *Don't.* Code made short by squeezing statements together isn't faster than code longer because the statements haven't been squeezed together. It still does the same number of things. In your case, you're introducing bugs by squeezing things together.

Comment: Ok! this is very helpful, but I'd like for you to clarify. Why is setting a default length 64 bad? What are alternatives? Also, have you seen the second code block I updated the question with? Thanks!

Comment: @user3692055, it's bad because strings can be of any size. If the string you use is shorter than this, the function will overwrite memory that doesn't belong to it. With enough ingenuity, this could allow someone to create a virus that targets your program. Your second snippet doesn't have the UB from using an incremented `i` multiple times in the same statement, but it still discards the result of `*clone++ = *string++`, which is intended as a null check, so it will always copy exactly 64 bytes.

Comment: yeah that makes sense to me, do you have a more sensible approach?

Comment: @user3692055 an alternative is to check the length of the string by using the strlen() function. You can remove the length parameter in your function and declare an int inside it. Then, you can write: length = strlen(string). You will need to include strings.h header.

Comment: @user3692055, I'd do something like this: http://pastebin.com/RAUtgb9B

Comment: @user3692055 my solution will work only if you want to copy the whole string. If you just want to copy a part of it, this won't work

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that! I totally forgot about checking the length. Also, from the pastebin, will the final clone value automatically have the NULL char if say (Length) < [sizeof original string]?

Comment: @user3692055, it will not, because basically nothing happens automatically in C. It is an error on my part. You'd have to write some code to do it. (Then again, you could also use `strncmp` from `#include <string.h>` for approximately the same functionality.)

Comment: @user3692055 I added an answer about what be said here

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! I'm coming from JavaScript, so that's why it's so interesting, I have to pretend I'm in the 70's when C WAS a high-level language.

Answer (score 2):

The code has Undefined Behavior:

The expression

```
(clone[i++] = string[i])
```

both modifies and accesses the object `i` from two different subexpressions in an unsequenced way, which is not allowed.  A compiler might use the old value of `i` in `string[i]`, or might use the new value of `i`, or might do something entirely different and unexpected.

Comment: that's great! exactly what I wanted was for somebody to point out something I wouldn't have readily predicted. I'm still learning C, and this is a lot of help.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer no.

1. Why return char and the function has no return statement?
2. Why 64?
3. I assume that the two arrays are of length `Length` - Add documentation to say this.
4. Why the ; on a new line and not after the statement?

...

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I decided to evolve my comments into an actual answer. Although this doesn’t address the specific piece of code in your question, it answers the underlying issue and I think you will find it illuminating as you can use this — let’s call it guide — on your general programming.

What I advocate, especially if you are just learning programming is to focus on readability instead of small gimmicks that you think or was told that improve speed / performance.

Let’s take a simple example. The idiomatic way to iterate through a vector in `C` (not in `C++`) is using indexing:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  v[i] = /* code */;
}
```

I was told when I started programming that `v[i]` is actually computed as `*(v + i)` so in generated assembler this is broken down (please note that this discussion is simplified):

- multiply `i` with `sizeof(int)`
- add that result to the address of `v`
- access the element at this computed address

So basically you have 3 operations.

Let’s compare this with accessing via pointers:

```
int *p;
for (p = v; p != v + size; ++p) {
  *p = /*..*/;
}
```

This has the advantage that `*p` actually expands to just one instruction:

- access the element at the address `p`.

2 extra instructions don’t seam much but if your program spends most of it’s time in this loop (either extremely large `size` or multiple calls to (the functions containing this) loop) you realise that the second version makes your program almost 3 times faster. That is a lot. So if you are like me when I started, you will choose the second variant. Don’t!

So the first version has readability (you explicitly describe that you access the `i`-th element of vector `v`), the second one uses a gimmick in detriment of readability (you say that you access a memory location). Now this might not be the best example for unreadable code, but the principle is valid.

So why do I tell you to use the first version: until you have a firm grasp on concepts like cache, branching, induction variables (and a lot more) and how they apply in real world compilers and programs performance, you should stay clear of these gimmicks and rely on the compiler to do the optimizations. They are very smart and will generate the same code for both variants (with optimization enabled of course). So the second variant actually differs just by readability and is identical performance-wise with the first.

Another example:

```
const char * str = "Some string"
int i;

// variant 1:
for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {
  // code
}

// variant 2:
int l = strlen(str);
for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
  // code
}
```

The natural way would be to write the first variant. You might think that the second improves performance because you call the function `strlen` on each iteration of the loop. And you know that getting the length of a string means iterating through all the string until you reach the end. So basically a call to `strlen` means adding an inner loop. Ouch that has to slow the program down. Not necessarily: the compiler can optimize the call out because it always produces the same result. Actually you can do harm as you introduce a new variable which will have to be assigned a different register from a very limited registry pool (a little extreme example, but nevertheless a point is to be made here).

Don’t spend your energy on things like this until much later.

Let me show you something else that will illustrate further more that any assumptions that you make about performance will be most likely be false and misleading (I am not trying to tell you that you are a bad programmer — far from it — just that **as you learn**, you should invest your energy in something else than performance):

Let’s multiply two matrices:

```
for (k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      r[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
    }
  }
}
```

versus

```
for (k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
  for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      r[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
    }
  }
}
```

The only difference between the two is the order the operations get executed. They are the exact same operations (number, kind and operands), just in a different order. The result is equivalent (addition is commutative) so on paper they should take the EXACT amount of time to execute. In practice, even with optimizations enable (some very smart compilers can however reorder the loops) the second example can be up to 2-3 times slower than the first. And even the first variant is still a long long way from being optimal (in regards to speed).

So **basic point**: **worry about UB** as the other answers show you, **don’t worry about performance** at this stage.

Comment: Very good answer. I will study this! Haha, in C, these things are gimmicks, because the compiler does a lot of heavy lifting. I'm not very familiar with the compiler, I understand the basics and I've read up on it. In JavaScript, I've done a lot of perfomance testing, and so those didn't convert well here. I completely agree that readability is all part of the aptitude of the design. So again, good answer!

Comment: Although I will say, that understanding performance is really a huge factor, and since these are all mathematical principles, understanding your language in the low-level concepts adds to a comprehensive awareness that transcends in the code itself. As I usually find though, it seems there is more left to understand! But without you I  wouldn't have known that, so thanks~!

Comment: I am not trying to undermine the importance of performance. Just that as you said now, you need a level of understanding of low level language, hardware architecture and compiler optimization algorithms that is well above average in order to write code that is performant, otherwise you are just throwing shots in the dark. First feel comfortable and confident writing correct code, then you can research how to profile and optimize a C/C++ application. You’re welcome, I am glad I made my point clear.

Comment: the difference in this regard between an interpreted program (e.g. JavaScript) and a compiled one (e.g. C) is that the translation between your code and the executed instructions has to be done at runtime, so an interpreter has to do this really fast, there is no time for complex optimization analysis. What is the point to make a section run in 200ms instead of 500ms if the algorithm to do this takes 800ms. In contrast, a compiler has time to analyze and optimize the code as this is done at compile (duh) and not at runtime.

Comment: Haha. This turned out to be a great discussion. I'm excited that there's so much to learn, and at the same time, I've gathered that it's not the biggest priority to consider performance on a micro-level at this point. If you have the spare time though, running personal benchmarks is a great way to explore methodologies, familiarize options, and spark question as to where and what to research. I can tell you have a lot of experience in C. It may take me a good while to get there.

Answer (score 0):

The second block of code is better.

The line

```
printf("cloneString = %s\n", clone);
```

there will never get executed since there a return statement before that.

To make your code a bit more readable, change

```
    while
    (
        *clone++ = *string++
    ,   --Length
    );
```

to

```
    while ( Length > 0 )
    {
        *clone++ = *string++;
        --Length;
    }
```

Comment: Wow, I'm really glad everybody's being so helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a better approach to your problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void cloneString(char *clone, char *string)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != strlen(string); i++)
        clone[i] = string[i];

    printf("Clone string: %s\n", clone);
}
```

That been said, there's already a standard function to to that:

```
strncpy(const char *dest, const char *source, int n)
```

dest is the destination string, and source is the string that must be copied. This function will copy a maximum of n characters.

So, your code will be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void cloneString(char *clone, char *string)
{
    strncpy(clone, string, strlen(string));
    printf("Clone string: %s\n", clone);
}
```